# jquery checkbox problem

Tags: jquery

Im having a problem with a piece of jquery code. Every time this piece of code is executed, it disables all the links in my page :( if i click on a link on a page... it doesn't to nothing.

```
// listen to every click on a checkbox
$('input[type="checkbox"].status').bind('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    // if the checkbox is checked
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        // increase counter
        statusCounter++;
        return;
    }

    // if the checkbox is unchecked
    if($(this).is(':not(:checked'))
    {
        // decrease counter
        statusCounter--;
        return;
    }
```

Any help? thanks

Comment: You seem to be missing some of the code as I don't see how that would in any way modify the functionality of your links.

Comment: the closing bracket } is missing at the end.

Comment: Also the closing bracket for the bind function and the semi-colon after it (so add `});` to the end). I assume this is just an extract. Could we have all the JS? It may be a different piece of script causing the problem.

Comment: thanks for all the fast reply's.
i found the problem in another piece of code in a documment.bind that was blocking the links :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of your return statements?  I don't see a point in having them where they are and returning nothing.  If you take them out, your unexpected behavior may go away.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally re-write that as follows:

```
// listen to every click on a checkbox
$('input[type="checkbox"].status').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    // if the checkbox is checked
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        // increase counter
        statusCounter++;
    }else{
        // decrease counter
        statusCounter--;
    }
```

It shouldn't alter the functionality at all, but it may help simplify things and make finding the problem a little easier.

I also noticed that it isn't a complete piece of code. You are missing `});` at the end. Could you provide all of your JS? It may be a different piece of script that is causing the problem.